# Plot dataframe entries using if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cartopy

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Rank    Name    Pop_2019    Pop_2018    Change  latitude    longitude   TC Risk
 0  1       Tokyo   37393129    37435191    -0.0011 35.682839   139.759455  1.0
1   2       Delhi   30290936    29399141    0.0303  28.651718   77.221939   0.0
2   3       Shanghai    27058479    26317104    0.0282  31.232276   121.469207  1.0
3   4       Sao Paulo   22043028    21846507    0.0090  -23.550651  -46.633382  0.0
4   5       Mexico City 21782378    21671908    0.0051  19.432630   -99.133178  0.0
```

I want to plot the latitude and longitude of cities where `'TC Risk'` = 1. Here is the code I use:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()
if data['TC Risk'].any()==1:
    ax.scatter(data['longitude'],data['latitude'], transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

However, this simply plots every single latitude and longitude point, not just the ones where `'TC Risk'` = 1. How would I amend my code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need boolean indexing and plot:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.stock_img()

plot_data = data[data['TC Risk']==1]
ax.scatter(plot_data['longitude'], plot_data['latitude'], transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```